# Log de auditoria de aplicação em desktop

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, arquivo, log

Pensando em uma aplicação Java *desktop* que esteja em funcionando em uma empresa, podemos nos deparar com situações que o usuário pode causar falhas em sua aplicação, neste caso poderia criar um *log* de erro e uma auditoria para saber qual erro foi causado e como o usuário chegou há aquele erro. Em relação de criar um *log* já tenho algo desenhando e planejado mas em termos de auditoria como poderia fazer.

- Criar uma tabela no banco e gravar tudo que realizado no sistema. (acho inviável e consumir demais banco de dados para armazenar estas informações).
- Criar um arquivo texto que armazena todo o processo realizado no terminal de uso, e registra todo o processo.

Gravar no arquivo texto seria o mais viável? Como fazer o registro de todos os processos, como cliques em botões e os campos que foram preenchidos ou não?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro precisa decidir o que vai gravar. Tentar *logar* cada ação do usuário parece inviável. Ficar monitorando os movimentos dele pode ser útil para analisar o uso da interface e como está a experiência, mas deveria ser usado em um momento específico e se tiver alguém que vai saber analisar os dados.

*Log* de uso, que é chamado de auditoria na pergunta, deveria gravar apenas o que realmente gera efeito no sistema. Até porque ações erradas do usuário não deveriam gerar erros na aplicação. Se isto ocorre o erro é do programador e precisa resolver.

Se vai *logar* o que é gravado no banco de dados, o melhor lugar para armazenar o *log* é o banco de dados. Não vejo problema algum em fazer isto. A não ser que a aplicação tenha problemas de arquitetura, mas aí é outro problema. Se acha que tem problema, demonstre isto. Não precisa ser necessariamente na mesma base de dados.

Tem várias vantagens em usar o banco de dados. Tem algumas vantagens em usar um arquivo texto no lado do servidor.

Não se esqueça que armazenar os dados no lado do cliente, ainda mais em texto puro, deixa o sistema vulnerável. Se o usuário fizer uma besteira ele tentará apagar isto.

O lado do cliente deve ser responsável pela interface com o usuário e nada mais. Regras de negócio devem ser garantidas ou gerar crítica específica no caso dela ser flexível. Isto deve ser feito ou no banco de dados, ou na aplicação, mas no servidor, não na interface.

Se tiver a arquitetura certa o processo de *log* se torna quase transparente. Até dá para ser 100% transparente com as ferramentas certas, ainda que possa diminuir a qualidade da informação em alguns casos.

Conforme for evoluindo poste perguntas específicas.

Ah, auditoria é processo de análise dos *logs*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Aqui onde trabalho, nos separamos *logs* e auditoria. Para *logs*, como erros de sistema, etc, utilizamos o [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), que nos possibilita (caso rodar em servidor), analisar em tempo real o que esta acontecendo e também filtrar somente por erro ou qualquer outro nível.

O Logback é super configurável, e no nosso caso, ele gera um arquivo por dia, e a cada dia, pode existir mais de 1 arquivo caso esse exceda o tamanho de 20mb. Todos os arquivos são compactados (pelo Logback), o que reduz muito o tamanho do mesmo. Também temos uma rotina para deletar isso, já que *logs* de 2 semanas atrás não nos importam mais.

Para auditoria usamos o MongoDB na nuvem. Temos um grande volume de dados e até hoje, o onico problema que tivemos, foi criar uma aplicação que facilite a leitura desses registros.

Num banco relacional, temos também uma tabela, gigante, contendo mais de 500gb de dados, e essa (na época não foi muito bem pensando) é usada só para escrita. Utilizamos técnicas de particionamento de tabelas, o que melhorou bastante, mas mesmo assim qualquer consulta é muito custosa. O que fazemos com ela é ter várias *triggers* filtrando os dados que chegam e mandando para outras.

Enfim, existem N soluções para isso, inclusive o Hibernate tem algo para isso. Como o @Maniero comentou, só não deixe o arquivo no lado do cliente, porque ele simplesmente pode apagar e dizer que foi "falha do sistema".

Bom, isso era só mais um comentário, mas não cabia tudo lá.